# Inverting Hessian using Generalized Inverse for Inference

Tags: inference, hessian

I am estimating a survival model with MLE. I use optim to maximize the likelihood function, and I intend to use the Hessian matrix returned by optim to get the standard errors (which lie on the diagonal of the inverse of Hessian). As it turns out that the Hessian matrix is singular and can not be inverted by R's default inverse function base::solve(). I can invert my Hessian using generalized inverse function MASS::ginv() though. What concerns me is that I got many very small standard errors, which render my coefficients suspiciously significant.

What do you think of using ginv() instead of solve() to invert Hessian for inference?

Comment: Which model are you fitting using optim? Does optim converge?

Comment: It's a split survival model. Optim did converge.

Comment: Did you try to use likelihood profiling? to get confidence intervals for the specific parameter(s) that you are interested in?

Comment: What are the eigenvalues of the Hessian?

Answer (score 0):

solve() fails when the likelihood profile for one or more parameters is flat around the maximum likelihood. It means that the standard error for this or these parameters is infinite.
ginv() can be seen as a trick (the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse of a matrix) assuming that standard error is 0 for this or these parameters. It is clearly wrong.
If this (or these) parameters are not of interest for you, this can be a good solution. But do not interpret these se !
The solution could be to use Bayesian MCMC rather.

Comment: the problem is that it may be a linear combination of parameters which is ill-identified, rather than a particular one, which would mess with the SE of all involved parameters.

Comment: Good point ! I didn't thought about this solution. Have you a solution to identify the set of parameters involved in this potential collinearity?